# SFTP libssh failure

Tags: c, ssh, sftp, libssh

I am using the libssh library and trying to create a new SFTP session. I keep getting an error message of

> ssh_packet_unimplemented:  Received SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED (sequence number 3)

I checked the syslog of the remote server and found the error

> dispatch_protocol_error: type 90 seq 3 [preauth]

For some reason I get this error when trying to use the following (taken from the [libssh doc](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html))

```
int sftp_helloworld(ssh_session session) {
  sftp_session sftp;
  int rc;
  sftp = sftp_new(session); // Freezes at this part
  if (sftp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating SFTP session: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
    return SSH_ERROR;
  }
  rc = sftp_init(sftp);
  if (rc != SSH_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing SFTP session: %s.\n", sftp_get_error(sftp));
    sftp_free(sftp);
    return rc;
  }
  sftp_free(sftp);
  return SSH_OK;
}
```

The only thing that is working is the actual ssh connection. The same error occurs whether I'm using SCP, SFTP or when opening a remote shell.

I've researched a lot regarding my issue, but couldn't find any remedies. Any help would be great.

**EDIT:**

On the Amazon EC2 server I looked through `/var/log/auth.log` and found this:

> sshd[24860]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu
>
> sshd[24860]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
>
> sshd[24930]: dispatch_protocol_error: type 90 seq 3 [preauth]

In the libssh code I set the `SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY` to `SSH_LOG_PACKET`, everything runs smoothly, but when it gets to the `sftp_new()` I recieve this error and it freezes at the `SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED` message,

> channel_open:  Creating a channel 43 with 64000 window and 32768 max
>   packet
>
> packet_send2:  packet: wrote [len=44,padding=19,comp=24,payload=24]
>
> channel_open:  Sent a SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN type session for channel 43
>
> ssh_socket_unbuffered_write:  Enabling POLLOUT for socket
>
> ssh_packet_socket_callback:  packet: read type 3
>   [len=12,padding=6,comp=5,payload=5]
>
> ssh_packet_process:  Dispatching handler for packet type 3
>
> ssh_packet_unimplemented:  Received SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED (sequence
>   number 3)

**EDIT2:**

I used the following code to connect to the server,

```
ssh_key pKey;
int rc = ssh_pki_import_privkey_file(PC_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pKey);

ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();

ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, PC_HOST);
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, PC_USER);
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &PC_PORT);
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &PC_VERBOSITY);

rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
```

I was confused by the [tutorial](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutorial.html). I might have not wrote the code to connect to the server properly.

Comment: Can you connect to the server using a regular SFTP client, at all?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yup, I can connect to the server using `ssh`, `sftp` and `scp`.

Comment: Collect all logs you can and edit them into your question. Server-side log (what SSH server is that anyway?), `sftp -vv` output, libssh log.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I updated the question with more error messages. Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you completed client authentication? "[preauth]" from the server's log probably means that user authentication is not yet finished, thus SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN cannot be processed by the server this far.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov I updated the question with the code I used to connect to the server. The tutorial on the libssh website confused me, so I might have not done it correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are definitely not authenticating. Unless you didn't post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html), after connecting to server you should authenticate yourself to it. I.e., if you want to authenticate with public key, add the following after successful call to `ssh_connect`:

```
int rc;
// ...
rc = ssh_userauth_publickey(my_ssh_session, NULL, pKey);
if(rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
    // error
} else {
    // all good, start SFTP/shell/etc
}
```